# mailman is forcing moderation of messages posted by members even with mod bit not set

Tags: mailman

My mailman server is holding all posted messages from users even though I've confirmed that they do not have the mod bit set.

I've confirmed that the from email matches the subscribed member (the message in the moderation list says its from a member).

The server was just setup, and the members just joined. Is there maybe something like for the first 24 hours they are still moderated?

Or is there some other setting, like a list or even global server setting that is forcing all posts to get moderated?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else who might encounter this issue in the future.

I found the mailman logs and noticed that the vette log had an entry which said "Message has implicit destination". This was caused by the fact that my test emails did not have a To: header in them. I was sending all the emails via telnet for testing because the DNS was pointing elsewhere. I never bothered to set the To: header. I only had the RCPT TO:.

So adding the header when using telnet solved the problem, and once the DNS is changed, using a mail client will also not be affected by this since they add that header automatically.